# Set JDK location for Android Studio without an Enviroment Vairable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cygwin

I am running Windows 7 and just upgraded my Android Studio and it is not working anymore. I get a dialog that says it cant find the jdk. I have version .9 now. I do not have admin rights so I can not edit my Enviroment Variables. Is there a way I can tell Android Studio where the JDK is. Maybe command line args? I havent found any source that outlines if there are any.

Please note that I can not run Android Studio, so I cant update it from inside the application.

Also, I do have Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Since, Android Studio was working before and only broke after the update, please check the Studio shortcut you're using to launch the IDE. By default, Android Studio points it to `studio64.exe`. If you have a 32-bit Java JDK installed use the `studio.exe` to launch the IDE.

---

If that doesn't help, see if you can create a `JAVA_HOME` **user** variable? You maybe able to do that even though you have a limited account. If you are unable to do so, as a last resort, move/copy the JRE (not JDK) into the Android Studio install location (right next to `bin`). You need to name the folder `jre` or `jre64` depending on which launcher you use `studio.exe` or `studio64.exe`.

Comment: I am clicking on them directly from the bin folder. I have tried both. The 32 bit one tells me to use the 64 bit one. The 64 bit one cant find the JDK.

Comment: What's the `java -version` output on console?

Comment: Running from a Cygwin command prompt:
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

Comment: That indicates 32-bit. Can you try creating a `JAVA_HOME` **user** variable? You maybe able to do that even though you have a limited account.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant, it asks for admin username/password before I can get to the dialog to set those variables.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. I download the Server JRE from the Oracle page. I then decompressed the gzip and untared it. I then then added to my ~/.bashrc file in cygwin "export JAVE_HOME=". Studio was able to find this.